# how does django model after text[] in postgresql

Tags: django, django-models

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to map PostgreSQL array field in Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400762/how-to-map-postgresql-array-field-in-django-orm)

I have a table wit one of the columns of datatype text[] in postgresql. May I know how do I access this column using django models orm? I'm aware that theres a commaseparatedintegerfield, but no such for text related fields. Do i use textfield or need to create a custom field for this?

Comment: You mean you're trying to store an array of strings in the DB? Don't do that. Each string should be in a separate row. You might need to create a separate table with a many-to-one relationship.

Comment: PostgreSQL array field support is now part of Django master (not in 1.7 though). See :  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield & https://github.com/django/django/pull/2485

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Django ORM supports PostgreSQL arrays. It's unsurprising, as this looks like a fairly PostgreSQL-specific feature. If you really have to use arrays, your best bet is to construct SQL queries as text by hand. Otherwise, just turn the array columns into tables, as Mark suggests; that is by far a more portable and conceptually clean solution (although the performance may be lower).

Comment: I'm using the column to store tokenized text actually. 1-1 with my unprocessed text. if i use 1 token per row, sounds like an overkill.

Comment: Databases are designed for large amounts of data, so don't worry. I would approach the decision as follows: 1) go with the solution that is simpler to implement, 2) if both are equally simple, go with splitting the array into rows, as it is less obscure.

Comment: "I don't think Django ORM supports PostgreSQL arrays" : That's going to change with https://github.com/django/django/pull/2485

Answer (score 1):

There are often times when the PostgreSQL array field is the right solution.  For instance, when working with a legacy database.  The [django-dbarray](https://github.com/ecometrica/django-dbarray) project on github adds support for this.  I haven't used it, but it looks like usage is basically:

```
from django.db import model
import dbarray

class Person(models.Model):
    birthdate = models.DateField()
    nicknames = dbarray.TextArrayField()
```