# How to map PostgreSQL array field in Django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have an [array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/arrays.html) field in my PostrgreSQL database of type text. Is there a way to map this into a Django model ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does django model after text\[\] in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213332/how-does-django-model-after-text-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to look into [django-dbarray](https://github.com/ecometrica/django-dbarray) on github.  It adds support for postgresql array fields.

I haven't used it before, but it looks like you just need to do:

```
from django.db import model
import dbarray

class ProfilingTestRun(models.Model):
    function = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    runtimes = dbarray.FloatArrayField()
```

Comment: db_index is not accepted on array fields ... is it even possible?

Comment: Since Django 1.8 you have https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Answer (score 4):

One of the other nice options is http://django-orm.readthedocs.org/ --- a library that adds bindings to many native postgres types.

Main drawback of `django-orm` is that as of today it has no working support for `south`.

Answer (score 4):

djorm-ext-pgarray also offer queries
http://www.niwi.be/2012/10/07/postgresql-array-fields-with-django/

Comment: This now seems like a better option than django-dbarray as it's better maintained. dbarray doesn't work for CharField arrays in its current form (though there is an outstanding pull request which apparently fixes this)

Answer (score 3):

Native support for PostgreSQL specific model fields is coming soon to Django (in the django.contrib.postgres.fields module):

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield
- https://github.com/django/django/pull/2485 : The corresponding pull request

Answer (score 2):

Since [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#new-postgresql-specific-functionality) there is a [django.contrib.postgress module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/) that adds support to [array fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) among other PostgreSQL data types.

For example you can do something like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class GoGame(models.Model):
    board = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.IntegerField(),size=19),size=19)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to subclass `model.Field` and write input and output methods.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#custom-database-types