# Migrate from Google App Engine Model to Pure Django System

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, refactoring

How can I rewrite this AppEngine specific code for pure Django Model system 
(without google api)

```
class A(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    description = db.TextProperty()
    isAdvanced = db.BooleanProperty()
    foos = db.ListProperty(db.Key)    
    bar = db.IntegerProperty()

    def get_foos(self):
        return db.get(self.foos)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you'll have to do it manually. Thankfully though, Django can do most of the work for you.

First, make sure you have the appropriate database settings in `settings.py`. You can find a detailed walkthrough of database configuration [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02/#cn54).

Once finished, run `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`. It'll dump `manage.py`'s output, which constructs the python code for the models, into `models.py`, which you can then add to the relevant Django application. You'll have to double check it, but it should take far less effort.

In addition, from personal experience, if it encounters any problems, it'll let you know. For example, both PostgreSQL's `money` and MySQL's `currency` fields are not recognized by Django's models, so it will emit `models.TextField()`, followed by `# This is a guess.`.

**EDIT:** Just found this article when Googling for it:
[Migrating from Google App Engine to Django](http://www.cloudartisan.com/2010/10/migrating-from-google-app-engine-to-django/)

**EDIT 2:** I just realized I probably didn't answer your question. This is (roughly) what it would look like, though I'd still recommend you run `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`.

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    isAdvanced = models.BooleanField()
    foos = # Dunno, a quick Google search doesn't turn up the equivalent
    bar = models.IntegerField()
```

To get a the `multiline` attribute for `name`, you may want to take a look at [this question](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/ec8fbd6cc4c7be47?pli=1) from Google groups or Google it yourself.

Comment: for foos it seems it's  models.ManyToManyField can you confirm that?

Comment: @Christophe I'll look into it, but from my understanding of Google's AppEngine docs, it seems more like a list of `models.ForeignKey`/SQL datatype.

Comment: ok, Thank you. do you know if model have simple Array (postgres have this type)

Comment: @Christophe After further research, there is no equivalent to AppEngine's `db.ListProperty` in Django's native ORM, as dragonx said. (There is a hack I found at http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/e480601b1d70425f , but it stresses that it is not production code.) In addition, Postgres's Array type is not supported out of the box; you would have to add this field functionality by subclassing `model.Field` and writing the class yourself. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400762/how-to-map-postgresql-array-field-in-django-orm for more.

Comment: Thank a lot  my english is not so good to find all the things you gave me.

Comment: @Christophe No problem. One last thing I think you might find useful is Django's documentation detailing how to make your own `model.Field`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/

Answer (score 2):

Edwin's answer is a good start.

I've been using django-nonrel, instead of the basic django.

django-nonrel comes with a module called djangotoolbox, that offers a ListField wrapper for a google ListProperty.  Normal django doesn't have an equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to rewrite all the db associated code with hand. I am in a similar situation. :-)