# Database saves multiple choice as [u'abc', u'cba']

Tags: python, database, postgresql

How can I prevent the postgreSQL database to save a multiple select as `[u'abc', u'cba']`? The field type is "text".

When displaying the entries on a website I want to show: abc, cba.

Comment: You mean `u''` ? It is just the unicode representation.

Comment: I assume you're using Python, from the syntax. If so, do NOT store Python array representations in the database - use PostgreSQL array support, or normalize into a side table.

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on keep that field as a text type then you can convert the list into your preferred text format

```
>>> ', '.join([u'abc', u'cba'])
u'abc, cba'
```

I don't think you should be storing that as text though, I think you're working with Django? It might be best to break the list into items and then make the relationships with the model. Then in your Django template you can display it in the format that you want.

If you want to use Postgres arrays, this might help: [How to map PostgreSQL array field in Django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400762/how-to-map-postgresql-array-field-in-django-orm)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Django. I'll try to break the list into items.